# HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized for accessing file on UNC

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory, unc

I have a ASP.NET website set up IIS7.5 on `Server1`. The website has a virtual directory uploads where physical path is `\\Server2\UploadFolder`.
The website URL is `http://Server1:8080/Default.aspx`.
When I hit the above URL I can upload file through page and the file gets uploaded to the virtual directory. Lets say I upload file uploadedfile.jpg.

Now When I hit `http://Server1:8080/uploads/uploadedfile.jpg` ideally the browser should able to get the file in response instead the browser shows error.

```
HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.
```

I have given access to IUSR and NETWORKSERVICE on folder `\\Server2\UploadFolder` still no help.

Am I missing anything? Any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to map the Drive for \\Server2\UploadFolder this folder

Comment: What identity is your application pool using?

Comment: I changed the identity to Application pool identity and now its working. Previously it was Specific User. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to map the Drive for \Server2\UploadFolder this folder

Could you please try [Link 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx) and [Link 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320268)? it may help you.